# Python 3 unicode ZWJ error with String replace

Tags: string, python-3.x, unicode

I need to replace ANSII characters with UNICODE (Sinhala). I use lists with a loop to do that as follows,

```
for i in range (len(charansi)):
    for j in range (len(charUni)):
        s = charansi[i] + ansimod[j]
        v = charUni[i] + modUni[j] 
        textSource = textSource.replace(s, v)
```

if we use n + uu as ANSII input, it should give නූ as Unicode out put. But instead of that, it gives න ූ

to clarify more,

```
charansi = n
ansimod = uu
charUni = න
modUni =  ූ
```

this න and  ූ must join without spaces. I think ZWJ (\u200D) plays a role here. so i tried

```
v = u"\u200D".join((consonantsUni[i], vowelModifiersUni[j]))
```

gives same result.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing, but this simply works:

```
#coding:utf8
charansi = 'n'
ansimod = 'uu'
charUni = 'න'
modUni =  'ූ'

v = s.replace(charansi+ansimod,charUni+modUni)
print(v)
```

Output:

```
නූ
```

Create a working example of the problem if this isn't what you want.

You could also use the following to make the characters more clear.  At least on my browser, the modifier didn't display very well.

```
charUni = '\N{SINHALA LETTER DANTAJA NAYANNA}'
modUni = '\N{SINHALA VOWEL SIGN DIGA PAA-PILLA}'
```

Comment: Than you verymuch for your answer @Mark, and I found that there's a rendering error in Ubuntu terminal too.